# TP($\omega_2$) and the continuum

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory

I think that in all classical models of TP($\omega_2$) we have $2^{\omega_0}=\omega_2$. Is there a known model of TP($\omega_2$) + $2^{\omega_0}>\omega_2$ at all?

Comment: What is $TP(\omega_2)$?

Comment: It would seem to be the tree property: every $\omega_2$-tree has an $\omega_2$-branch.

Comment: Yes, I meant the tree property, sorry! 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think Spencer Unger in "Fragility and indestructibility of the tree property" proves that if one adds an arbitrary number of Cohen reals to Mitchell's model, then the tree property survives (see http://www.math.cmu.edu/~sunger/).